# how to make the divs at the same size

Tags: django, django-models, bootstrap-4

how can i make all the divs at the same size

i am using django ??

```
 <div class="row text-left">

                    {% for meg in objj %}
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">

                        <!--Image-->
                        <div class="view overlay rounded z-depth-1-half mb-3">
                            <img src="{{ meg.img.url }}" class="img-fluid" alt="Sample post image" height="100%"
                                width="150%">
                            <a>
                                <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
                            </a>


                    {% endfor %}
```

models:

```
class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    body = models.TextField()
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auQX2.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are doing, it is going to generate the divs of the same size only.

But then you are **forgetting** the `</div>` inside the for loop.

Fixing that will work for you.

```
{% for meg in objj %}
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
    <!--Image-->
    <div class="view overlay rounded z-depth-1-half mb-3">
        <img src="{{ meg.img.url }}" class="img-fluid" alt="Sample post image" height="100%"
            width="150%">
        <a>
            <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
        </a>
    <!---- !!!!!!!! you are missing the below 2 closing divs --->
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Concur. Closing tags are important for frameworks such as Django, Bootstrap, etc.